# Add static function to \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Im trying to add a static function to [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html).

I have tried the following:

Created a class:

```
class CustomCollection extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
{
    public static function test()
    {
        die('test');
    }
}
```

And then I have tried including the class.

But without luck I get the error message: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::test()`

The error message is given calling `User::where('id', 1)->get()->test();`

Comment: Those methods never use your class. You can't extend something and then hope that other things magically use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use your collection instead of the one provided by Eloquent, add a method in your model:

```
public function newCollection(array $models = [])
{
    // of course, adjust your namespace accordingly
    return new CustomCollection($models);
}
```

It will override this method in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class:

```
/**
 * Create a new Eloquent Collection instance.
 *
 * @param  array  $models
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public function newCollection(array $models = array())
{
    return new Collection($models);
}
```

Now every time the Eloquent queries return collection (for example, using `YourModel::all()`), the custom collection will be used and the methods that you added will be available.

Source: [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#collections)

Answer (score 1):

Since i cant use the comment function i have to answer, although i dont feel like it should be flagged as an answer. Your error point out that you are calling the Collection::test().The method test in the Collection Class does not exists! You extended CustomCollection with Collection and added a method to CustomCollection not to Collection!